# Q&A: Prove if two spanning sets are equal

Tags: linear-algebra

### Question 4: Alon Lalezari

This is how i solved this question:

$Let \ u,v,w,t \in V$

Find if: $Sp${$u+v-3w, 2v-w, t+w, v+w$} = $Sp${$u,v,w,t$}

This is how i finally solved this question with your help.

If you find mistakes, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

### Question 4: Alon Lalezari

$Let \ u,v,w,t \in V$

Find if: $Sp${$u+v-3w, 2v-w, t+w, v+w$} = $Sp${$u,v,w,t$}

---

The right spanning set is already a linear combination of the right spanning set vectors.

We will check if the right spanning set is also a linear combination of the left vectors.

Let: 
$$u = (1,0,0,0)$$
$$v = (0,1,0,0)$$
$$w = (0,0,1,0)$$
$$t = (0,0,0,1)$$

Let $a,b,c,d \in R$

$$ a(1,1,-3,0) + b(0,2,-1,0) + c(0,0,1,1) + d(0,1,1,0) = (1,0,0,0)$$
$$ a(1,1,-3,0) + b(0,2,-1,0) + c(0,0,1,1) + d(0,1,1,0) = (0,1,0,0)$$
$$ a(1,1,-3,0) + b(0,2,-1,0) + c(0,0,1,1) + d(0,1,1,0) = (0,0,1,0)$$
$$ a(1,1,-3,0) + b(0,2,-1,0) + c(0,0,1,1) + d(0,1,1,0) = (0,0,0,1)$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &|1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 &|0 \\ 
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 &|0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &|0 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ -4/3 \\ 0 \\ 5/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &|0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 &|1 \\ 
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 &|0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &|0 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1/3 \\ 0 \\ 1/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &|0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 &|0 \\ 
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 &|1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &|0 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ -1/3 \\ 0 \\ 2/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &|0 \\ 
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 &|0 \\ 
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 &|0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &|1 
\end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow X = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 1/3 \\ 1 \\ -2/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$

There is a solution for each system, so as a conclusion, the sets can be represented as linear combination of each other.

Comment: Hebrew explanation: https://youtu.be/OdpTE28wZgo

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$
u'=u+v-3w,\quad v'=2v-w,\quad w'=t+w,\quad t'=v+w
$$
and you can look whether the matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
is invertible.

With an easy Gaussian elimination
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& \begin{aligned}R_2&\gets R_2-R_1,\\ R_3&\gets R_3+3R_1 \end{aligned} \\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets\tfrac{1}{2}R_2 \\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+R_2 \\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3/2
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_4\gets R_4-R_3 \\
\end{align}
So, yes, the matrix is invertible.

If you use its inverse, you are able to express $u,v,w,t$ as linear combinations of $u',v',w',t'$.

The inverse can be computed as
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
-4 & 1 &-1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 7 &-1 & 2 &-2
\end{bmatrix}
which means that
$$
u=u'-4v'+7t',\quad v=v'-t',\quad w=-v'+2t',\quad t=v'+w'-2t'
$$

This is essentially equivalent to your solution, but you messed up the matrix. Note that the question doesn't ask to find the inverse, only to state whether the two subspaces are equal.

Comment: How does it help you that the matrix is invertible?

Comment: @Alon It means that the systems you are solving by hand have (unique) solution.

Comment: Ok understood. If we had infinity number of solutions, the conclusion would be different?

Comment: @Alon There can't be an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: And why my solution is incorrect? mess up the matrix?

Comment: @Alon You have a $1$ at position $(4,4)$ that should be $0$.